Does the Life bonus from Uncanny Fortitude include Magick that's been primed?
Hephaestus's Uncanny Fortitude Boon says "Gain bonus Max Life based on your Magick limit." Some conditions can Prime Magick to make it unusable, such as Poseidon's Flood Control Boon or the Oath of the Unseen's Vow of Arrogance.
Does Primed Magick count towards the Max Life bonus for Uncanny Fortitude? For example, let's say my Magick Limit is 100, then I get an ability that Primes 20 Magick, lowering my usable Magick to 80. I then get a common Uncanny Fortitude which grants +20% Max Life from Magick. Will my Max Life bonus be for 20HP or 16HP?

Yes, Primed Magick counts when calculating the Max Life bonus for Uncanny Fortitude. So in the given scenario, you would get a bonus of 20HP.
I tested this by getting Uncanny Fortitude while having Magick primed from Trusty Shield. Initially I had a Magick Limit of 95 with 30 Primed and a Max Life of 120 HP. I then picked up an Epic Uncanny Fortitude Boon, which gave +40% Max Life from Magick. My Max Life increased to 158 HP, an increase of 38 HP, or 40% of my unprimed Magick Limit.

